# What is the meaning of $dX(t)$ when $X(t)$ is a random process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

In the book about Stochastic Differential Equations, the term $dX(t)$ appears everywhere and I have a question about the meaning of it.

Because for every $t\in [0,T]$, $X(t)$ is a random variable instead of a number, compared to a function $f:R\to R$, I don't understand the $dX(t)$, is it a differetial of $X(t)$?

Also I see the Itô's Integral$\int_{0}^{t}fdW(t)$, where $W(t)$ is the Brownian motion and we can get $\int_{0}^{t}fdW(t) = I(f)(t,\omega)$ by definition.

I also wonder what is the definition of $fdW(t)$, because $I(f)$ is also a random variable.

Comment: $X(t)$ is a stochastic *process*, i.e. a random variable evolving through time, so that $\mathrm{d}X(t) = X(t+\mathrm{d}t) - X(t)$ corresponds to its differential indeed, which captures its evolution after an infinitesimal interval $\mathrm{d}t$, as any differential.

Comment: $dX_t$ is meant as an Ito integral, so this boils down to the characteristics of the Ito integral. For $X_t$ of bounded variation (like $X_t = t$), this is a pathwise Riemann-Stieltjes integral. For general continuous $L^2$ local martingales like Brownian Motion, it exists as an $L^2$-limit of integrals of piecewise constant processes against the Brownian motion, which are just finite sums.

Comment: If you are reading a book about SDEs and have no trouble with $\int_{0}^{t}fdW(t) = I(f)(t,\omega)$ the question is slightly astonishing. When in that book $dX$ appears everywhere the authors must have introduced the stochastic integral with respect to slightly more general processes than just Brownian motion. In short (perhaps that was your question): $dX$ has no meaning when it comes stand-alone. It is a short notation for a stochastic integral.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for your comment, you say $dX$ is the integral but accroding to Abezhiko, $dX$ is $\mathrm{d}X(t) = X(t+\mathrm{d}t) - X(t)$, so I am a little bit confused about the definition.

Comment: @Alex Thanks but I am confused with the Ito integral because by definition it should be $dW(t)$ instead of $dX(t)$

Comment: We are fully into repeating everything that your book should cover. There is nothing wrong with Abezhiko's intuitive explanation but rigorously you have to put a $\int_0^t$ in front of all equations that contain stand-alone $dX\,.$ Stochastic processes are usually not differentiable w.r.t. $t\,.$ Please read that book patiently or pick one that explains this better.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for advisor and I have found the definition :)